# PDO Variable Update Error

Tags: php, pdo

these are my query codes. Please help me.
PDO Error: Array
PDO Eror Code: 00000

```
        <?php if ($_POST){
                    $title = trim($_POST['title']);
                    $content = trim($_POST['content']);
                    $id = $_GET['id'];

                    $save = $PDO->prepare("UPDATE `news` SET `title` = :title WHERE `id` = :id");
                    $save->execute(array(
                                                        "title" => $title,
                                                        "id" => $id
                                                    ));
                    print_r("Error: ".$save->errorInfo());
                    print $save->errorCode();
                }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It the OK status code.

You always print error but you should to print that only when the query failed.

```
$sql = $save->execute(...)
if ($sql === FALSE) {
    print ('Error: ' . $save->errorCode());
}
```